# How to iterate over a Rapidjson Document which is itself a JSON array using a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11, rapidjson

I've  been trying to parse a JSON string that looks like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "rapidjson/document.h"

void main()
{
    char const *json_str = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse(json_str);
    // Ninja edit to fix json_str.IsArray()
    if(d.IsArray())
    {
        for(auto &e: d)
        {
             std::cout << e.GetInt() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the code fails to compile with "begin() is not declared in this scope" and other errors of the same sort.

This indicates that I'm trying to iterate over something that can't have std::begin() and std::end() called on it.

The rapidjson tutorial [here](https://rapidjson.org/md_doc_tutorial.html) only explains how to iterate over an array retrieved using GetArray(), and not at the document level. I also went through the docs, and searched on Google without much luck.
I also tried using:

```
for(auto &e: document.GetArray()) // Similar to the tutorial's code, which calls d.GetObject()
```

But this fails saying that GenericDocument (Document is a typedef, AFAIK) does not have a member called GetArray(). For that matter, it doesn't have a GetObject() member either.

On the other hand, iterating using a counter works just fine.

I might be missing something obvious since it's been a long day, and it's 12:00 AM in my part of the world, but I'd really appreciate any pointers on where I might be going wrong, and how to complete this task.

Answer (score 1):

`d.GetArray()` is the correct way to cast a document to an array.

However in your example you're calling `IsArray()` on the input string instead of the `Document` instance.

The following code works for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <rapidjson/document.h>

int main() {
    char const* json_str = "[1, 2, 3, 4]";
    rapidjson::Document d;
    d.Parse(json_str);
    if (d.IsArray())
    {
        for (auto& e : d.GetArray())
        {
            std::cout << e.GetInt() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the error in my code. I've fixed the code in the question and added a comment highlighting what used to be there. Unfortunately, the code still doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 with rapidxml-dev installed. I'm starting to think that this may be a version issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: Wait a minute, you're using rapidXML to parse JSON??

Comment: It's Rapidjson. Typo in the comment. I'm super tired, and should probably go to sleep. Lol!

Comment: That sounds like a good plan. The `#include "rapidxml...` also looks suspicious.

Comment: I'll edit that, and then head to bed. Thanks for the help @rustyx.